# Friendly URLs and allowing users to have control over them

Tags: php, codeigniter, friendly-url

I have a CI application with a CMS and I have been wondering how I can give the user control over the urls for their blog articles they will publish. I understand about the routes.php file but I'm just wondering how I can allow the user to change the url to something they want instead? I have not done this before so I am unsure of how to do this in CI.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into codeigniter if this is possible? Do you have any knowledge on how to make your own MVC framework? Your question is not clear, we fix specific problems and try to stay away from opinions on SO. Please reformat your question and you might have more success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way is to use a URL Slug to refear to the article.
You can give the possibility to insert the title of the article and then set a slug for it, in this way when a user click the slug you should run a query in the db using the slug to search the article.

table example:

```
id_article
title
body
slug
```

example form:

```
Title: <input type="text" name="title">
Body: <textarea name="body"></textarea>
Slug: <input type="text" name="slug">
```

Le't suppose this entry for the post:

```
Title: Hi, this is my first post!
Body: Wow i'm so happy
slug: my-awsome-post
```

when you create a link to the post you shuld use as id the slug, for example:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/blog/show/my-awsome-post">Read more</a>
```

whan you run the query in your model you can use as where clausole the slug:

```
$this->db->get_where('table', array('slug'=>$slug));
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you mean something like the title of a post a la wordpress, so that the title becomes part of the URL?

You need to set up a custom routing for the controller in application/config/routes.php, e.g.

```
$route['posts/(:any)'] = "posts/posts_method/$1";
```

Posts_method refers to your method that searches for a post with the given variale.